# Connecting braided water connector with 1/2" female connection to 3/4" male tub inlet

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, bathtub

I'm currently using a 3/4" x 1/2" bell reducer and 1/2" nipple to connect my tub faucet's inlet flare (I think that's the right word?), but no matter what I do, I'm getting leaks on both ends of the reducer. Per the picture, I'm using PTFE tape.

Is there a way I can directly connect the braided connector to the inlet flare? The faucet also came with a riser nut with a washer inside which I'm currently not using.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need special adapters built for older tubs that use the old style bathcocks. If you go to a plumbing shop (*not* big-box hardware store) and ask for "claw-foot tub faucet adapters" they will probably know exactly what you are looking for:

[image]

Comment: Also, nicer looking. There are a number of online “fancy” versions available for visible plumbing.